# Case insensitive search

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

Can anyone guide me how to add a case insensitive option in this following query.

```
db_select('abcd', 'f')
$result = $query
  ->fields('f')
  ->condition('f.def', '%hai%','LIKE')
  ->execute();
```

If I use the following query I'm getting a result which equals to lower case of 'hai' , but I need the result which contains both upper and lower case of 'hai'.

Comment: What is the format/string used in `$query`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the case sensitivity factor is not determined by your DB wrapper, but instead by the collation of the column that you are querying. The name of the collation should end in '**_ci**'.

Comment: Thans dude ... I have changed my collation in db. Then its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Either use a `upper()` function to cast both the query and the column to uppercase or choose specific collation. In your case it seems `upper()` is the only way.